# Changing transmittivity of polarizing filters for different wavelengths

Tags: optics, photons, measurements, polarization

I suppose, that a polarizing filter works as described [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/177678/46708):

> The polarizing filter absorbs or reflects some of the photons in the light beam, which is why the energy/power measured after the polarizer is reduced.

Furthermore any filter works only for some range of the EM spectrum, outside this range the filter is not transparent, e.g. no light is going through.

In my understanding between these to states has to be a range of wavelengths, where the transmission for unpolarized light has to be between zero and less than 50%.  Rotating such a filter, for a polarized light beam the intensity behind the filter has to be not a sine function. For example, the absolute impermeability of the filter will not only be at 90° and 270°, but from 70° to 110° and from 250° to 290°. Has this situation been observed?

Answer (score -1):

> In my understanding between these to states has to be a range of wavelengths, where the transmission for unpolarized light has to be between zero and less than 50%.

There's no requirement for this - if you know that a filter is fully linearly polarizing at a given wavelength $\lambda_0$ (i.e. at that wavelength its transmission is 100% for H polarization and 0% for V polarization) then you can infer *nothing at all* about its behaviour elsewhere. It is indeed unlikely that this property will hold for all wavelengths (indeed, no known device does that), but you cannot know

> Rotating such a filter, for a polarized light beam the intensity behind the filter has to be not a sine function.

This is **absolute hogwash**. Since you're changing the polarization angle but not the wavelength, the wavelength dependence products out, and you're left with a Malus's law dependence. **All linear optics have that sinusoidal dependence.** The behaviour you're describing is unphysical.

> For example, the absolute impermeability of the filter will not only be at 90° and 270°, but from 70° to 110° and from 250° to 290°. Has this situation been observed?

That situation is unphysical, and as such it has not been observed. The only way to fool yourself into thinking that you've observed it is by having signal that is too low to resolve completely, followed by utterly-incorrect handling of the experimental sensitivity during the analysis. If a filter has a region of "absolute impermeability" (i.e. exactly zero-percent transmissivity) over an interval between 70° and 110°, then that means that the filter is fully opaque for all incident polarization angles.

---

Note that it is possible, at least in principle, to build a linear-optical element which is fully polarizing but whose transmission axis rotates from H to V over some given region of the spectrum. Given a white-light source, though, this will basically act as a de-polarizing filter (and it certainly won't act in the utterly unphysical behaviour you described in [this previous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/439531/8563)).